Do the mailer settings for batch size etc also apply to scheduled reminders?
I am trying to set up several Scheduled Reminders for event registrations. The amount of mails per reminder can be a few hundred.
I was wondering if the mailer settings for batch size etc also apply to scheduled reminders?
I mean settings like: mailer batch limit, mailer throttle time, and mailer job size
I am asking because of performance reasons and smtp limits.
